# USB serial data, network, database and GUI, should I go for multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, multiprocessing, pickle

I am designing a program in Python which

1. reads data via usb in two second interval from arduino to a Sqlite table (128kB each read outs)
2. Process the incoming data and store the results on another table
3. finally query the data on the table and show them on GUI created by tkinter and send the same data on the network to a server.

The question is for which part should I use multiprocessing or threading? Do I even need them? If I run first part from a separate Python file on background does it use necessarily different cpu core?

EDIT:
I found about pickling, now the question is:
is it good idea to pickle a 1kb string every 3 seconds, of course in the ramdrive? and depickle in another script.
I tested already two script and it is working, but I am not sure if this solution can be used in long term running?
It looks promising! specially when I dont see my selft stuck in multithreading or multiprocessing modules and seems like OS will assign necessary cores and threads.

Comment: "Should I use multiprocessing?": write it with threads first (for concurrency), and then adapt to processes if you are running out of CPU

Comment: Using multiprocessing with complex objects coming from Python library is really *painful* unless your code is totally embarrassingly parallel. Threads will only speed up your application when it is IO bound or the GIL is relaxed (which is often not the case). Beside performance, threads help to avoid blocking issues. However, async is the way to go (when it can be used) since thread also force you to protect your code with locks in most cases.

Comment: I was thinking to write a script to handle inputs from arduino and store it in a RAM Drive Sqlite database file, and another script to read data from the same file and run the gui. First script runs in the background and second one one top. In this case the OS will handle the multiprocessing as needed I guess and coding will be quite easy if the solution is making sense!